# How to retrieve header names from H2O GBM Model object in Python?

Tags: python, h2o

I am running H2O with Python.

So far, what I am able to do is build a GBM model and print its data. Below is my sample code.

```
gbm_model = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(ntrees=100, max_depth=4, learn_rate=0.1)
gbm_model.train(predictors, response, training_frame=trainingFrame)
print(gbm_model)
```

Also, here is a sample snapshot when printing `gbm_model`.

[GBM Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybYF6.png)

**What I want to achieve is retrieve each data (with its header name)** so that I can map and display those data on my own way. So, I tried to access the Variable Importances data by looping through it.

```
print("Loop through Variable Importance Items")
varImp = gbm_model.varimp()

for varImpItem in varImp:
    for item in varImpItem:
        print(item)
    print(" ")
```

For additional info, `gbm_model.varimp()` returns a `ModelBase` object.

[gbm_model.varimp()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAcg.png)

Then, this was the data that I retrieved.

[GBM Model (Variable Importances Loop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5uK.png)

As what can be seen, it was only the data itself. The header names (`variable`, `relative_importance`, `scaled_importance`, `percentage`) were not included for the display.

**I want to ask, is there a way to retrieve the header names for this? If so, how can I do it?**

Answer (score 0):

once your gbm model is trained, you can access the variable importance using the following line :

```
import pandas as pd
varImp = pd.DataFrame(gbm_model.varimp(True))
```

From there you have a pandas dataframe and it is easy to access the columns names or even slice the dataframe anyway you like.

Cheers !